# selectors not working entirely

Tags: jquery

I am populating a `<div>` with the `html()` function, after a link is clicked. Basically, I don't want the page to refresh, but put stuff inside the `<div>`.

That works fine.  However, I am passing a link into the `<div>`, and trying to select that too!  It literally takes me to a different page, rather than populating the next `<div>`, as I expected.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".link1").click(function(){ $("#div1").html("<a href='#' class='link2'>click here</a>"); return false; });
  $(".link2").click(function(){ $("#div2").html("Just Text"); return false; });

}); 
</script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use [`live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live):

```
$(function() {
  $("a.ink1").live("click", function() {
    $("#div1").html("<a href='#' class='link2'>Click here</a>');
    return false;
  });
  $("a.link2").live("click", function() {
    $("#div2").html("Just text");
    return false;
  });
});
```

The reason is that when you bind an event with click() it does so on elements that *exist at the time* not elements you create later. That's what `live()` is for.

Comment: shouldn't that be `$("a.link1").live( "click", function() {...` and `$("a.link2").live( "click", function() {...`?

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".link1").click(function(){ $("#div1").html("<a href='#' class='link2'>click here</a>"); renderlink2(); return false; });
  renderlink2();

}); 

function renderlink2(){
  $(".link2").click(function(){ $("#div2").html("Just Text"); return false; });
}
</script>

<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```